# Javascript mousedown and mouseup on different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to develop a word search game in JS which looks like this : https://jquery-wordsearch-game.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo.html

BTW I am not using that guy's plugin and instead, trying to develop on my own.

I am using the following code to fire a handler to highlight the cells when a user clicks and moves over them.

`$('#puzzlecontainer').on('mousedown','.block',myHandler);`

The problem is that the mousedown event is fired on the first cell only. I want handlers to fire on all cells in the path of the mouse.

Also how can I make this compatible with touch events ? I tried touchmove and touchdown.

Please help

### UPDATE

With Shusl's help I added the following code :
var ismosedown = false;

```
        $('#puzzlecontainer').on('vmousedown','.block', function(){
            globalvars.ismousedown =true;
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });

        $('#puzzlecontainer').on('vmouseover','.block', function(){ 
            if(globalvars.ismousedown){
                $(this).addClass("active");
            }
        });

        $('#puzzlecontainer').on('vmouseup','.block', function(){ 
            globalvars.ismousedown = false;
        });
```

**vmouseover** works as desired on a desktop browser. But it is not working on my Android phone and tablet. Please help.

Comment: On `mousedown` you need to attach a `mousemove` event which captures each `event.target` element.

Answer (score 0):

Fire a function to add and remove an event to be fired on mouseenter. Add this event when the mouse is down and remove it when mouse is up to stop highlighting...

```
$('#puzzlecontainer').on('mousedown','.block',startSelect);// Run when down
$('#puzzlecontainer').on('mouseup','.block',stopSelect);// Run when up

function startSelect(){
    $('#puzzlecontainer').on('mouseenter','.block',myHandler);//Add Handler on enter.
    // Fire the mouseenter event for the current element or it will not highlight.
    $(this).trigger('mouseenter');
}
function stopSelect(){
    $('#puzzlecontainer').off('mouseenter','.block',myHandler);//Remove Handler because mouseup.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mouseover` event on each cells and set a flag true in `myHandler` . check if it is true and then treat it as `mousedown` event

```
var ismosedown = false;

    $('#puzzlecontainer').on('mousedown','.block', function(){ ismosedown =true; } );
   $('allcells').mouseover(function(){
          if(ismosedown ){ // do works
           }
    }).mouseup(function(){
           ismosedown = false;
     });
```

Comment: Thanks. How about touch events ? 
I tried touchdown and touchmove. What is the equivalent of mouseover for touch events ?

Comment: if you are using jQuery mobile then vmouseover is equivalent to mouseover

Comment: I have updated the code in my question on your suggestion. But it is not working in touchscreen devices. Please help

Comment: Sorry I dont have much knowledge about touch events. but you can see all supported jQuery mobile events on http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html . there are many events listed.

Comment: Why are you using globalvars.ismousedown while you have declared your ismousedown variable as window.ismousedown? is globalvars is same as window for browsers?

Comment: I use an object called globalvars for storing variables with global scope. That way the global namespace wont be polluted

Comment: But as in code 'var ismosedown' is not part of that globalvars. but that  would not create any problem.

Comment: I modified your code a bit. changed `var ismosedown` to `globalvars.ismousedown`. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I got confused because code you shared in update has 'var ismosedown = false;' (not highlighted). Sorry, I could not help. I think you should ask fresh question.